# How to get my text to follow my player in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm creating a game with the Phaser 3 framework. My game uses a scrolling camera, so according to what I searched, the easiest way to display a score would be with a container. I am trying to use a tween to make sure it follows the player, but I can't seem to figure out the correct properties.

I expect the score to start directly above the player, and to move wherever he moves.

If there is a better way to do this than using a container, feel free to change it.

```
//Camera to follow the skater
    this.cameras.main.setBounds(0, 0, 3000, gameHeight);
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(skater);

// ...some code in between...

 //Scoreboard
    scoreBoard = this.add.container(skater.x, 50);
    scoreText = this.add.text(skater.x, 50, "SCORE: 0", {fontSize: '56px', color: '#fff'});

    scoreBoard.add(scoreText);

    this.tweens.add({
        targets: scoreBoard,
        x: scoreBoard.x + skater.x,
        ease: 'Linear',
        duration: 1,
        delay: 1,
        yoyo: false,
        repeat: -1
    });
```

NOTE: All this code is only in the `create()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. In the **`update()`** function, set the **`scoreText`** variable to **`skater.body.position.x`** like so:

```
function update() {
    scoreText.x = skater.body.position.x;  
}
```